# Manipulating file contents in python

Tags: python

So, I have text file like this:

```
1 21
21 5
21 1
1 3
```

I want to manipulate this file to get an output like this:

```
1 21
21 5
1 3
```

(ie) If there is an occurrence `u v` , I need to eliminate `v u` from the file.

Note: I know I can do this using a nested for loop.
I need a better efficient way to do this .

Comment: What  have  you  tried  so  far?

Comment: I have taken a line from the file. Extracted the two numbers.Swapped it. Searched the file for occurrence of it. Elimated the occurrence.

Comment: If you just want a general suggestion, I think you should use a `dict` or `set` to store the pairs. Go over the file, check if the pair is in the dict - if it's not, add it and output it

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be to keep track of pairs that you've already seen in a `set`:

```
seen = set()
for line in file:
   u, v = line.strip().split()
   if (v, u) not in seen:
       print("{} {}".format(u, v))
       seen.add((u, v))
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work.